# Simplex number calculation (all dimensions) in python

Tags: python

How can I calculate simplex numbers in all dimensions?
Example:

```
dimension:     2|      3|      4|
simpl(1)       1|      1|      1|
simpl(2)       3|      4|      5|
simpl(3)       6|     10|     15|
simpl(4)      10|     20|     35|
simpl(5)      15|     35|     70|
```

First I considered about a recursive implementation (in python):

```
def simplex(n, dim):
    if dim == 1:
        return n
    else:
        i = 1
        ret = 0
        while i <= n:
            ret += simplex(i, dim-1)
            i+=1
        return ret
```

The algorithm works, but because of the recursion its really slow, especially if your dimension number is 5 or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop to solve the problem.
This is as you're just re-writing a for loop.
Using a for loop you can change the loop to a comprehension, and take the `sum` of it.
This allows you to get the code:

```
def simplex(n, dim):
    if dim == 1:
        return n
    dim -= 1
    return sum(simplex(i, dim) for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

However this can be simplified.
When dim is the bullet point the function is:

1. \$n\$
2. \$\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n} i\$
   \$= \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}\$
3. \$\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n} (\Sigma_{j = 1}^{i} j)\$
   \$= \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}\$
4. \$\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n} (\Sigma_{j = 1}^{i} (\Sigma_{k = 1}^{j} k)))\$
   \$= \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)}{24}\$
5. \$\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n} (\Sigma_{j = 1}^{i} (\Sigma_{k = 1}^{j} (\Sigma_{l = 1}^{k} l))))\$
   \$= \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)(n + 4)}{120}\$

Since we're getting a pattern, we know that the top part of the fraction is:

\$\Pi_{i = 0}^{dim - 1} n + i\$

And if we use [oeis to find the denominator](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+6%2C+24%2C+120&sort=&language=english&go=Search) it says it's probably the factorial sequence.
And so it's likely:

\$\frac{\Pi_{i = 0}^{dim - 1} n + i}{dim!}\$

This is actually really easy to write in Python.
And so you can get a significant speed up.

```
from functools import reduce
from math import factorial
from operator import mul

def simplex(n, dim):
    return reduce(mul, (n + i for i in range(dim))) // factorial(dim)
```

Comment: Good point, but I actually knew the iterative solution already at the time of asking the question (I just asked to share this in the community). As you can see, I answered the question too. I have two mentions to you: do you need the double Slash before factorial(dim)? and I like the while loop more than the for loop, because I expierienced weird things with the order of execution in for loops

Comment: @Aemyl I didn't see your answer when I started and finished mine, but it was a thought provoking question, :). To answer your 'mentions', (1) You need either `//` or `/`, I chose `//` as it matches the functions range. (2) I don't know how I can help you like `for` loops, but I will not retract my encouragement for you to use them. As they objectively make the function much cleaner than the equivalent using a `while`.

Comment: I didn't want you to retract your aspect of using for loops :) I just wanted to explain why I use while loops.

Answer (score 2):

- consistency: spaces around operators (esp. `+=`) is not always the same, you should stick to a space before and a space after.
- conditions: since you return from your first `if`, you don't need the `else` clause. This saves an indentation level and help distinguish the general algorithm from the special case.
- iteration: you don't need a `while` loop with an explicit index. `for` loops are prefered in python.

  ```
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
      ret += simplex(i, dim - 1)
  ```
- additions: the `sum` builtin function should be faster than an explicit accumulation loop. You can combine it with a generator expression for better efficiency.

Overall, the code could be written:

```
def simplex(n, dim):
    if dim == 1:
        return n

    return sum(simplex(i, dim-1) for i in range(1, n+1))
```

---

As regard to the efficiency part, since your are computing results for the lower dimensions several times, you may want to use some form of caching. Take a look at the several techniques of [memoization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Comment: though for loops are prefered in python, I like while loops more then them, because in my opinion (and in python's) explicit is better than implicit. Another point is, I expierienced some really weird things with for loops (the order of iterating through list for example)

Comment: @Aemyl Out of "use <name> as a variable to iterate over <stuff> and do …" and "check this <condition> before you do … over and over again"; I don't think the latter is more explicit when, well, iterating over some stuff. And I don't know what you are trying to do with your lists, but order of iteration is always consistent in a for loop. I’d understand if you said `set` or `dict`, but not `list`.

Comment: sorry, I guess it was on dictionaries

Comment: @Aemyl Then the arbitrary ordering is built into the language. If you want to be able to control it, you may want to have a look at `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatly, there is a iterative variant based on a sum formula by Gauss (the Gauss formula is only for the 2nd dimension):

```
def fac(n):
    i = 1
    e = 1
    while i <= n:
        e*=i
        i+=1
    return e

def simplex(n, dim):
    i = 0
    ret = 1
    while i < dim:
        ret*=(n+i)
        i+=1
    ret /= fac(dim)
    return ret
```